# Can I run a torrent client + Plex Media Server as "services"?

Tags: software-recommendation, torrent, daemons, plex

I'm using an old iMac as a torrent client & Plex Media Server.

But I would like those to run as "services", i.e., not as part of a User account, and without having to log in.

Comment: Transmission works according to this thread: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30310/torrent-client-for-os-x-that-can-be-shared-between-multiple-user-accounts

Comment: Services are tasks that can be called from  the serve menu in applications. Things that ruin in the background like you say are daemons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **launchd**, [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) and [this script](https://gist.github.com/pavel-mukhanov/8375567#file-rtorrent-plist) to launch rTorrent as a daemon.

This post describes how to install rTorrent and run it as a daemon using tmux.
First, install software:

```
$brew install rtorrent --with-xmlrpc-c
$brew install tmux
```

Parameter –with-xmlrpc-c is needed to use GUI clients with rTorrent.
rTorrent needs terminal to run. We provide virtual terminal using tmux.
To autostart rTorrent create launchd sript and place it to

```
/Library/LaunchAgents/rtorrent.plist
```

The script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>rtorrent</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/tmux</string>
        <string>new-session</string>
        <string>-s</string>
        <string>rtorrent</string>
        <string>-d</string>
        <string>rtorrent</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Load script:

```
$sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/rtorrent.plist
$launchctl list | grep rtorrent
```

If all is ok you will see something like this:

```
- 1 rtorrent
4868 - 0x7f872252ff90.anonymous.rtorrent
```

Now you can attach to tmux session and start using rTorrent:

```
$tmux attach-session -t rtorrent
```

To restart script unload it and load again:

```
$sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchAgents/rtorrent.plist
$sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/rtorrent.plist
```

To view launchd logs run:

```
$sudo launchctl log level debug
$tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep launchd
```

The rTorrent installation is over, now you can install GUI client.
There is free client for Mac OS X called Nativa. It not very good, but you can try it. To use any client you need to add this in your .rtorrent.rc:

```
scgi_port = 127.0.0.1:5000
```

[Source](http://pmukhanov.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/installing-rtorrent-on-mac-os-x/)

Comment: I have added the step from your source to the answer posted. In the future, please don't simply link offsite. We like answers to be complete and robust, not just links to other places on the net. This isn't Google. Many thanks for contributing.